# trying to find domain name in VM

Tags: windows-7, command-line-interface, virtual-machines

I requested helpdesk my VM computer name to be added to the domain. after I run the SystemInfo command in the command line, I get WORKGROUP instead of the desired domain name. Help desk insist that they have added to the domain because they could ping to my computer. How do I make sure that my VM (virtual machine) machine was added to the desired domain name???

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can ping because of netbios. It's not joined to the domain. Double check by running sysdm.cpl clicking change, and then checking the domain settings.